# How to create a folder on desktop and move the dropped file in it with AppleScript?

Tags: zip, applescript, directory, ipa

I want to make an Applescript. I want to drop a file on it (.app file) and than it should create a folder named "Payload" in the same directory as file that was dropped. Than it should copy the file that was dropped to the Payload folder.  The Payload folder should now be zipped. Than the extension should be changed from .zip to .ipa. And the .ipa file should now be renamed to the file name that the droppped file has. And at the end it should delete the folder that was created (if not already) and the dropped item should be deleted too.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much.

Didn't understand it? Please drop a comment. :)

Comment: What did you try so far? Which part is causing trouble? The zipping? The file management? You cannot expect someone to write the whole script.

Comment: I tried to make a folder and that worked but I don't know how to copy the file into that folder and zip it and remove the old ones...I'm not so familiar with AppleScript so I tried it with Automator and got it working but the only problem is in automator that I cannot remove the old files. :/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming that you're scripting the Finder with a `tell application "Finder"` step. If that's the case, check out the `move` command in the Finder's dictionary to move the file, and `delete` for removing the file.

Regarding zipping, when I've needed to compress a file with AppleScript, I've found that using a shall command with `do shell script` and the zip command line tool (type `man zip` in a Terminal window or take a look at [the online man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/zip.1.html)).

If you're unfamiliar with `move`, `delete` and `do shell script`, check out the AppleScript dictionary for the Finder (for `move` and `delete` and the Standard Scripting Addition (for `do shell script`).

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with Chuck's answer, you could use [Folder Actions](http://www.tuaw.com/2009/02/16/applescript-exploring-the-power-of-folder-actions-part-i/) to accomplish this...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a Folder action as the anwser up

First, create your folder.

Puis, write this AppleScript

```
on adding folder items to theAttachedFolder after receiving theNewItems
-- Get the name of the attached folder
tell application "Finder"
    set theName to name of theAttachedFolder

    -- Count the new items
    set theCount to length of theNewItems

    -- Display an alert indicating that the new items were received
    activate
    display alert "Attention!" message (theCount & " new items were detected in folder " & (quoted form of theName) & "." as string)

    -- Loop through the newly detected items
    repeat with anItem in theNewItems

        -- Process the current item

        -- Move the current item to another folder so it's not processed again in the future

    end repeat
end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Instructions for adding a folder action to a folder:

[Watching Folders Instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WatchFolders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH39-SW1)

Or In Automator you can add an AppleScript with this code, you just need to set a variable, from automator and return it to AppleScript, for the folder you dropped in the targetFolder.

```
set theFolder to "Folder_child:Folder_Grandchild:Folder_Great-Grandchild"
set theNewFolder to "Folder_First_Great_Grandchild"

if FolderExists(theFolder) = true then

    --display dialog "Exists " & theFolder & " !"
    --delete the file
else

    --display dialog "Missing " & theFolder & " !"
    -- do nothing or something else
end if

--handler for checking if exists theFolder/thePath

on FolderExists(theFolder) -- (String) as Boolean
    tell application "System Events"
        if exists folder theFolder then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end if
    end tell
end FolderExists
```

This is all I found for now.

Best regards